# Maximum purchased toys time out

Tags: javascript, algorithm

So yeah, I have a homework sort of question which I've solved but keeps giving a timeout error on test cases and I can't figure out why.

You need to buy your nephew toys for his birthday. But you only have limited money. However, you want to buy as many unique toys as you can for your nephew. Write a function that will return the max number of unique toys you can buy.

The arguments to the functions are the integer array costs that contains the costs for each toy and the integer budget which is the max amount of money you can spend.

Return the integer representing the max number of unique toys you can buy

Constraints

If N is the number of toys and K is the budget...
1<=N<=105
1<=K<=109
1<=price of any toy<=109

Sample Input

costs: {1, 12, 5, 111, 200, 1000, 10}
budget: 50
Sample Return Value

4
Explanation

He can buy only 4 toys at most. These toys have the following prices: 1,12,5,10.

so this is what I wrote and it keeps giving a timeout error on 10 testcases. I can't figure out why

```
function maxPurchasedToys(costs, budget) {

    var costsLess=[];
    var removeFromArray=function(arr, value){
        for(i in arr){
            if(arr[i]==value){
                arr.splice(i,1);
                break;
            }
        }
        return costsLess;
    }
    //First let's get a new array consisting only of costs that are equal to or below the budget
    costs.map(function(x){x<budget?costsLess.push(x):1;})
    var sum=0;
    costsLess.map(function(x){sum+=x;});//Get the sum of budget

    while(sum>=budget){
        var max=Math.max.apply( Math, costsLess );
        costsLess=removeFromArray(costsLess,max);//Remove the biggest element to ensure that the costs fall within budget
        sum=0;
        costsLess.map(function(x){sum+=x;});//Get the new sum of budget

    }

    return costsLess.length;
}
```

I tried the following cases: the original test case, [5000,2000,20,200],50 and a few more. All executed fine

Comment: which case that give you timeout?

Comment: you probably need to set your time out higher, since these problems can actually take a while: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with your code yet. But anyways this might help: 
Calling maxPurchasedToys([25, 25], 50) causes it to infinite while loop. On the other hand maxPurchasedToys([20, 25], 50) does not cause an infinite loop.

Comment: shit ofcourse. too late now. @shashank thanks man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply sort and iterate?

```
function maxPurchasedToys (costs, budget) {
    var i = 0, sum = 0, count = 0,
        l = costs.length;

    costs.sort(function (a, b) { return a - b });

    while ( i < l ) {
        if ( budget >= sum + costs[i] ) {
            sum = sum + costs[i];
            count++;
            i++;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ya5MK/

---

And if you are able to use ES5 array methods (you're using `map` , so I guess you can), use this:

```
function maxPurchasedToys (costs, budget) {
    var sum = 0, count = 0;
    costs.sort(function (a, b) { return a - b }).some(function (cost) {
        if ( budget >= sum + cost ) {
            sum = sum + cost;
            count++;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    });

    return count;
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ya5MK/1/

Answer (score 0):

you can try with another approaching like **sort** your costs array **ascending** and see how far you can fetch on that array

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp

```
function maxPurchasedToys (costs, budget) {
    costs.sort(function(a,b){return a-b});
    count = 0;
    money = budget;
    for (i=0; i<costs.length(); i++){
        if (money > costs[i]){
            money -= costs[i];
            count ++;
        }
        else{
            break;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```